# MSSQL datetime between in PHP doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, between

Here is sample code that works fine in Dbvisualizer but doesn't work in php script.

```
select
convert(varchar, oh.date,101),
oh.id
from oh
where oh.state=1 and convert(varchar,oh.date,104) between '17.12.2015' and '17.12.2015'
order by oh.id desc,date desc
```

In Dbvisualizer it returns rows in selected date range, but in php it returns all records from the table. 
mssql.datetimeconvert  has no affect. Where is a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't convert the date to varchar to perform a string comparison. Let SQL Server convert your date strings to dates so that a date comparison can be made. Secondly, your BETWEEN lists the same dates so the only records returned will be from midnight on 17/12/2015. This SQL would be preferable:

```
select convert(varchar, oh.date,101), oh.id
from oh
where oh.state=1 and   oh.date between '2015-12-17' and '2015-12-17'
order by oh.id desc,date desc
```

If this doesn't work can you post your PHP code?

Comment: if i don't convert date to string, it would use time stamp, which i don't need, so in that case , i should be use that period to select  records for one day 17th (between '2015-12-17' and '2015-12-18')  that's first, second , anyway that wouldn't solve the problem, in Dbvis code work's fine, even without conversion, but in PHP, without conversion it doesn't select  rows at all. full PHP code would't help, SQL query identical. because problem or in SQL configuration or PHP-SQL. using mssql.datetimeconvert affecting like this:

Comment: mssql.datetimeconvert=On
date looks like this:  Dec 20 2015 10:52:38:633PM
mssql.datetimeconvert=Off
like this :  2015-12-20 22:52:38

Comment: **code with conversion:**  
`select
convert(varchar, oh.date,101),
oh.id
from oh
where oh.state=1 and convert(varchar,oh.date,104) between '17.12.2015' and '17.12.2015'
order by oh.id desc,date desc`  
**result DbVis : all records with 17th december**
**result PHP : all records from table**  
**code without conversion:**  
`select
convert(varchar, oh.date,101),
oh.id
from oh
where oh.state=1 and oh.date between '17.12.2015' and '18.12.2015'
order by oh.id desc,date desc`  
**result DbVis : all records with 17th december**
**result PHP : empty result**

Comment: eventually i can solve my problem by exploding date by year, month and day, and put it in the SQL where clause. but it kind of dog-nail. it must be more natural and pretty solution